# Need Code Explanation in Basic Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

Below is a code I am trying to understand. My confusion is that basic_loss is a !D array or tensor with 1 element. So loss1 also should have same value when tf.reduce.sum is executed. Similiarly loss2 should also have the same value as basic_loss. But neither of them have same values when I try to execute.What could the reason for this?

```
import tensorflow as tf
    anchor = tf.random_uniform([1 , 128], dtype=tf.float32)
    positive = tf.random_uniform([1 , 128], dtype=tf.float32)
    negative = tf.random_uniform([1 , 128], dtype=tf.float32)
    pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)), axis=-1)
    neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)), axis=-1)
    basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), 0.3)
    loss1 = tf.reduce_sum(basic_loss)
    loss2 = tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0)
    print(basic_loss.eval())
    print(loss1.eval())
    print(loss2.eval())
    sess.close()
```

Output : [-1.5216954]
-2.0545285
[0.72764665]

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the code under a `tf.Graph` and `tf.Session`? In TF 2.0, using those is not encouraged because they don't work in an intuitive way.